# Is there a way to use Powershell to read local IE 11 cookies and replicate their data to other users on the same system?

Tags: powershell, cookies, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

I have a web based system that is called by a local PC system. The web system allows/controls interaction with a IP accessible device. Due to the simplistic nature of the base application interface to the web system (of which I have no control over), I have had to create a local cookie (using a web based configuration form) that stores site/install specific configuration information that is then used by the web system to interact with the internet accessible device for the installed site. The configuration is somewhat complicated. All of this already works and has been deployed to the initial customer site.

The issue is the PCs that are involved could be used by multiple people (in this instance 10 PCs that can be used by 10 or more employees each) with distinct logins to the PC(s) in question. This means setting up this complicated web configuration on each PC, 10 times. Lots of tedious room for errors.

I understand that I can not just copy a Win10 IE11 cookie from one user to another on a PC BUT is it possible to use Powershell to read the initial cookie that is built, extract the cookie information, and replicate/create a new cookie for all other users on that PC loading the new cookie with the same information in the base cookie?

I understand that I would likely need to run this from a user account with local admin right (in order to access the cookie area of other users) and can live with that if it avoids all the repetitive setup.

Is it possible to use Powershell and .Net to read a local cookie (given the URL) and extract the data from that cookie to be used to build new cookies for all other users on that PC for the initial URL?

Can't use IE plug-ins. Have not tried much else.

No code to show.

I am hoping for some code examples that demonstrate how to read from an existing cookie and how to write/create a cookie and load it with data, from Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer examples of powershell scripts below will help you to read cookies.

```
$url = "https://www.linkedin.com" 
$webrequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable websession 
$cookies = $websession.Cookies.GetCookies($url) 

# Here, you can output all of $cookies, or you can go through them one by one. 

foreach ($cookie in $cookies) { 
     # You can get cookie specifics, or just use $cookie 
     # This gets each cookie's name and value 
     Write-Host "$($cookie.name) = $($cookie.value)" 
}
```

And if you're using PowerShell 2.0 and below, use System.Net.HTTPWebRequest

```
$url = "https://www.linkedin.com" 
$cookiejar = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer 
$webrequest = [System.Net.HTTPWebRequest]::Create($url); 
$webrequest.CookieContainer = $cookiejar 
$response = $webrequest.GetResponse() 
$cookies = $cookiejar.GetCookies($url) 

# Here, you can output all of $cookies, or you can go through them one by one. 

foreach ($cookie in $cookies) { 
     # You can get cookie specifics, or just use $cookie 
     # This gets each cookie's name and value 
     Write-Host "$($cookie.name) = $($cookie.value)" 
}
```

Reference:

[Getting Cookies using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Getting-Cookies-using-3c373c7e)

**I did not get any examples for creating new cookie file from the existing files and share that cookie files with other users.**

Comment: I encountered that example via an earlier web search and if I understand the code correctly, it allows you to read what cookies a site ($url) will create/set. It does not appear to allow reading of existing local cookies created by a site as a result of a previous visit. I don't want to go to the site and get the new cookie data, I want to read the data stored locally from a prior visit. Thanks.   Or am I misunderstanding the code?

Comment: I try to find the examples for accessing the existing IE cookie for specific site but I did not get any useful information regarding that. you can try to run and check the above example, whether you are getting the required information or not. If you are getting all the required information than it can solve your issue.

Comment: That does not work as the local cookie data includes site/user specific GUID data to differentiate this configuration from others on other PCs at same location. I need to be able to fetch the local cookie data for target site from current logged in user and then use fetched data to create new cookies for all other existing users on that PC. That is the goal anyway. Am pursuing alternate solutions but this type of approach logically makes sense and would be easier that other options. Just might not be possible... :(

Comment: Did you try to open cookie folder manually and try to copy the cookie file for that specific site and paste it on other machine? you can first check it by doing the process manually to find whether this will even work or not. than after you can try copy file using power shell.